# How to combine server-side redirect with user notification

Tags: http, redirect

I understood that [client-side redirect with the META tag is discouraged](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback), and HTTP redirects should be used instead. But of course I want to notify users that they should update their bookmarks. How to do that then in a clean way and without using discouraged approaches?

Comment: The simplest is probably to redirect to a location like `https://example.com/newlocation?redirected=1` and then when the new location is loaded check if there is a redirected query